# Tomcat Server Publishing issue in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, tomcat7

When i am trying to start the server i am getting below exception

```
Could not publish to the server.java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
```

**Technologies**

JSF2,Primefaces3.5,Tomcat7,Java7,GSON2.2.4

**Oprating System**

Ubuntu13+

**IDE**

eclipse Kepler

I just noticed when i am removing GSON2.2.4.jar then everything working fine but after adding this jar nothing working and even server not started.

[image]

Comment: Can you add the full stacktrace?

Comment: @whoami see attached screen shot

Comment: I get tons of similar exceptions every day. Keep calm and clean up Tomcat. Or restart it.

Comment: i did that but no any progress

Comment: Here if i am removing GSON2.2.4.jar then server working otherwise not working

Comment: Can you provide us a full stacktrace (there must be full one in workspace logs or in tomcat logs)? Maybe a bug in a library? Also, if your application works without gson, than you do not need to include it in war :)

Comment: @madhead i need gson.jar for because passing data i am using gson

Comment: Ok, waiting for stacktrace :)

Comment: when ever i am trying to start then server or clean the server i am geting above exception in eclipse

Comment: Look, you go to your `.metadata` directry and trying to find some kind of logs. Also, check your Tomcat installation directory for helpful logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue when i am adding this in pom.xml

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

its creating this issue when i run `mvn install` i got this error

```
[ERROR] error: error reading /home/hariom/.m2/repository/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.2.4/gson-2.2.4.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
```

So i replaced this dependency with this one

```
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

now everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

. I have just got the same problem . I fixed it updating the pom dependencies from the pom.xml file

Answer (score 0):

By just restarting your system it can solve your problem.

Comment: Not a good Approach.You may get negative points for posting this as a answer.

Comment: I have just give the solution which helped me.

Comment: Agree but it can be added as a comment

Comment: Agree but for that I need reputation.

Comment: @DA BE Active and Participate in SO u will get reputation easily