# JSF+HighCharts Integration Issue

Tags: jsf, primefaces, highcharts

I am usinf JSF2+Primefcaes+GSON for Highcharts and my JSF page is

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <ui:composition>
    <h:head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function renderChart(divId, chartType, chartTitle, chartData, categories){
                var options = createOption(divId, chartType, chartTitle, categories);
                options.series = $.parseJSON(chartData);
                //chart.xAxis[0].setCategories($.parseJSON(categories));
                var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
            }

            function createOption(divId, chartType, chartTitle, categories){
                var options = {
                    colors: ['#058DC7', '#50B432', '#ED561B', '#DDDF00', '#24CBE5', '#64E572', '#FF9655', '#FFF263', '#6AF9C4'],
                    chart: {
                        backgroundColor: {
                            linearGradient: [0, 0, 500, 500],
                            stops: [
                                [0, 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'],
                                [1, 'rgb(240, 240, 255)']
                            ]
                        },
                        borderWidth: 2,
                        plotBackgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, .9)',
                        plotShadow: true,
                        plotBorderWidth: 1,
                        renderTo: divId,
                        type: chartType
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'JVM Heap Memory Usage Chart',
                        style: {
                            color: '#000',
                            font: 'bold 16px "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif'
                        }
                    },
                    subtitle: {
                        text: 'Source: http://www.askkuber.com',
                        style: {
                            color: '#666666',
                            font: 'bold 12px "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif'
                        }
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        ridLineWidth: 1,
                        lineColor: '#000',
                        tickColor: '#000',
                        categories: $.parseJSON(categories),
                        labels: {
                            style: {
                                color: '#000',
                                font: '11px Trebuchet MS, Verdana, sans-serif'
                            },
                            formatter: function() {
                                return this.value;
                            }
                        },
                        title: {
                            style: {
                                color: '#333',
                                fontWeight: 'bold',
                                fontSize: '12px',
                                fontFamily: 'Trebuchet MS, Verdana, sans-serif'

                            }
                        }
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        minorTickInterval: 'auto',
                        lineColor: '#000',
                        lineWidth: 1,
                        tickWidth: 1,
                        tickColor: '#000',
                        title: {
                            style: {
                                color: '#333',
                                fontWeight: 'bold',
                                fontSize: '12px',
                                fontFamily: 'Trebuchet MS, Verdana, sans-serif'
                            },
                            text: 'Heap Memory Usage'
                        },
                        labels: {
                            formatter: function() {
                                return this.value +'MB';
                            },
                            style: {
                                color: '#000',
                                font: '11px Trebuchet MS, Verdana, sans-serif'
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        area: {
                            stacking: 'normal',
                            lineColor: '#666666',
                            lineWidth: 1,
                            marker: {
                                lineWidth: 1,
                                lineColor: '#666666'
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        formatter: function() {
                            return ''+ this.x +': '+ Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 0, ',') +' MB';
                        }
                    },
                    legend: {
                        itemStyle: {
                            font: '9pt Trebuchet MS, Verdana, sans-serif',
                            color: 'black'

                        },
                        itemHoverStyle: {
                            color: '#039'
                        },
                        itemHiddenStyle: {
                            color: 'gray'
                        }
                    },
                    labels: {
                        style: {
                            color: '#99b'
                        }
                    },
                    series: []
                };

                return options; 
            };
        </script>
   </h:head>

    <h:body>
        <h:form prependId="false">

            <p:poll interval="5000" oncomplete="renderChart('container','area','Sample Chart', '${chartController.chartData}', '${chartController.categories}');" 
                      action="#{chartController.loadChartData}" id="chartvalue_btn" />

            <div id="container" style="width: 100%; height: 500px"></div>  
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
    </ui:composition>
</html>
```

But when i am trying to run this page i am getting white blank page . Can anyone tell me where can be issue in the page.

Comment: You've provided too little information to tell what's going on. Is your application server running correctly? Do you get any errors? If place some static text on the page is it visible?

Comment: i have added f:view textbox visible but chart not prepared yet

Comment: Try adding update="@form"  to the poll tag

Comment: @dratewka i am getting weird issue my project needed GSOn jar but when i am adding it i my tomcat is not working http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18164582/tomcat-server-publishing-issue-in-eclipse

Comment: Could you show what is generated in HTML in this line: `<p:poll interval="5000" oncomplete="renderChart('container','area','Sample Chart', '${chartController.chartData}', '${chartController.categories}');"` ? When you try to validate in http://jsonlint.com/ your variables output: `${chartController.chartData}`  -is  it returning any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Primefaces and highcharts may use diferent versions of JQuery. So you should comment the line

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

about Jquery, once Primefaces has a built-in Jquery lib.

In addition, you can see the error that gives you the blank page looking to your browser console  - F12 at Chrome and Firefox - and look for the nature of error that shows you the blank page.